# how to use spring boot to handle different search?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

What's the best practice to create search function in spring boot with spring data jpa?

```
@GetMapping("/search")
public List<Hotel> getAllByCriteria(@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> criteria) {
    if (criteria.containsKey("cityPublicId")) {
        String cityPublicId = criteria.getFirst("cityPublicId");
        if (criteria.containsKey("amenity")) { 
            List<String> amenities = criteria.get("amenity");
            return svc.findAllByCityAndAmenities(cityPublicId, amenities);
           }
        return svc.findAllByCity(cityPublicId);
    }
    //currently only support one amenity filtration
    else if (criteria.containsKey("amenity")) {
        return svc.findAllByAmenities(criteria.get("amenity"));
    }
    return null;
}
```

Currently I have to identify all possible combination of criteria to use corresponding method, Is there a universal way to handle all condition? Or at least not hardcoding all possible combination.

PS: If I want to filter result by multiple amenities, may I use findByAmenitiesContains(set)? Where a Hotel entity has a set of amenity. Do I have to create custom query using @query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have the following options:

- create the query programmatically from the input data using a [custom method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations). This gives you maximum flexibility but also requires the most work.
- [Use a specification](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications). Almost the same flexibility and almost as much work.
- [Use query by example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example). Very little work, limited flexibility.

Regarding the PS: [The capabilities of query derivation are well documented](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods).

Comment: May I ask how to handle integer with query by example? then given link only treats string.

Comment: The same. You just can't specify the kind of matching because it only does equals matching.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIR you can use different request payload entities to handle the same endpoint

```
@GetMapping(path = "/search", params = { "cityId" })
public List<Hotel> getAllByCriteria(ByCityPublicId byCity) {
    return svc.findAllByCity(byCity.getCityPublicId())
}

@GetMapping(path = "/search", params = { "cityId", "amenity" })
public List<Hotel> getAllByCriteria(ByCityPublicIdAndAmenity byCityAndAmenitities) {
    return svc.findAllByCityAndAmenities(byCityAndAmenitities.getCityPublicId(), byCityAndAmenitities.getAmenitities())
}

@GetMapping(path = "/search", params = { "amenity" })
public List<Hotel> getAllByCriteria(ByAmenity byAmenity) {
    return svc.findAllByAmenities(byAmenity.getAmenity());
}
```

Comment: It's basically same as creating 'if" in one method. I wonder if I can get multiple values for the same request params such 2 amenities. If possible, what will be the link address?